# Persistent TODO filtering and editing at the same time?

Tags: org-mode

I would like to focus on only `TODO`-type headlines and also be able to edit or add headings at the same time.

My Ideas how to achieve this would be

- **a sparse tree**, that refreshes itself. The default behaviour is that ohter neigbouring headlines are revealed if I toggle a heading or add a new one.
- **a minor mode** that constantly hides all `DONE` tasks (which maybe already exist?)
- **add/edit** `TODO` at a certain location **via agenda**, which does the persistent filtering already.

I am shure there are 100 more ways to do this in emacs. If you happen to know one, please do share it.

If you know how to implement one of the above ideas, please do share, too.